# CSS Transition not working with media query

Tags: html, css

for some reason I can't get my transitions to work with my media queries. They work just fine if I add a hover on my element. This is what my code looks like. 
    
    
    
        
        Responsive NavBar

```
    <main>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-cont">
                <a id="logo">Breiden Busch</a>
                <a id="hamburger"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="list">
                <a id="about" class="nav-buttons">About</a>
                <a id="contact" class="nav-buttons">Contact</a>
                <a id="social" class="nav-buttons">Social</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </main>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

#logo {
line-height: 51px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-weight: 600;
margin-left: 10px;
font-size: 18px;
transition: .5s;
}


@media (min-width: 600px) {

#hamburger {
    display: none;
}

nav {
    background: none;
    display: flex;
}

#logo {
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="box">Resize your browser into 600px</div>
<style>
    #box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        transition: .3s ease-in;
    }

    @media (max-width: 600px) {
        #box {
            background: red;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Interesting. I have this in my code and it breaks all of my other transitions: `nav {
    height: 51px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    transition: .5s;
}`

Comment: that's only a sample for better css transitions

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why but it was because of the `display: flex;` property on the `nav` element. If you remove it or move it of the media query, it works fine :

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #hamburger {
      display: none;
  }

  nav {
      background: none;
  }

  #logo {
      background: blue;
  } 
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d5u7sL1z/3/)